# Probability of random card from deck

Tags: probability

Take a random card of a deck. Let A be the event that the card is hearts. Let B be the event that the card is a king, queen, or ace. Are these events independent? Standard deck of 52, no jokers.

I say yes they are independent. Event A is not dependent on event B when getting a card from the deck.

My question is, what are your thoughts on my conclusion?

Comment: Are there any jokers in the deck?

Comment: @PeterShor no, my apologies, forgot to put that, will now.

Comment: Do you know how many duplicates of this question there are???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of independance : P(A) = P(A|B) or P(B) = P(B|A)

let A : Heart , B = King

P(A) = 13/52 = 1/4 and P(A|B) = 1/4

or

P(B) = 4/52 = 1/13 and P(B|A) = 1/13

Answer (score 0):

> I say yes they are independent. Event A is not dependent on event B when getting a card from the deck.

Yes, but *why* can you assert this?  A little more justification will demonstrate that you aren't just guessing would be nice. Examiners look for that.

Hint: Perhaps mention how Ace, Kings, and Queens are distributed among each of the four suits, and what that means.

Answer (score 0):

In such a standard deck of cards any event described entirely
in terms of suits is independent of any other event described
entirely in terms of denominations.

The criterion for independence of events A and B is that
P(A and B) = P(A)P(B).

Consider the event {Heart}. There are 13 of them so P{Heart} = 13/52 = 1/4.
Also you can find that there are 12 ways to get Ace, King, or Queen.
so P{AKQ} = 12/52.

You will find that the intersection (Ace, King, or Queen of Hearts)
corresponds to three cards, so its probability 3/52.

Because (13/52)(12/52) = 0.05769231, and also 3/52 = 0.05769231
the two events are independent.

Now organize these ideas, using whatever notation and symbols are used in your textbook
and expressing 0.05769231 as a fraction of integers in lowest terms,
and you'll have a nice answer.